# UITableview bottom is cut off on iphone5

Tags: xcode, uitableview, iphone-5

Let me preface this by saying this works perfectly on the iphone 4 - retina and regular.

I have a grouped table that has 4 sections. to set it up i use the dispatch_async stuff in viewWillAppear to grab the information from a server - and then call reloadTable when the server returns.

after the table has been reloaded with the correct information, when i try and scroll down i see more cells but it gives resistance as if i had already reached the end of the table even though there are 3 or 4 more table cells to show and bounces back.

there is one cell that has an image and some text that i use cell.addsubview to add some subviews to it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

but all the other cell heights are normal (44)

I am using IB to have the grouped table view and don't set the frame,bounds, or anything with it in my code - just set the various tablecell heights using the correct function.

does anyone know why it would work perfectly in the iphone 4 (i can scroll down to the bottom and see all the cells) and not in the iphone 5?

Thank you.

Comment: is autorize and autolayout checked in your storyboard? If yes UITableview will adjust automatically to Iphone-5 screen size

Answer (score 0):

I had autolayout checked in the Xib files.

To fix the problem i set self.view.frame.size.height to 568 in the top view controller (i was using a navigation conroller that loaded table views). once i did that, all the child views worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem to fix like below optimized way

if your using autoLayout don't be hardcode just use constraints

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to use XIB but i always use like this

```
tableview.frame = cgrectMake(0,320,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-64);
```

64= nabvar height(44)+ top bar (22);

hope this help :)